# How to spread text on multiple pages depending on text size?

Tags: python, pymupdf

What I tried

```
doc = fitz.open()
page = doc.new_page()
text = 'Long text'
tw = fitz.TextWriter(page.rect)
tw.append((20,40), text, small_caps=True)
tw.write_text(page)
doc.ez_save('test.pdf')
```

How to spread text on multiple pages depending on `text` size?

Font, text size should stay the same, it should extend to the amount of pages needed and write the appropriate pieces there.
I did not find the solution here.

Comment: Could you please include a https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimal_reproducible_example ?

Comment: @Chris This is a Minimal reproducible example.